# Casting a Delphi interface to TObject* in C++ Builder and proper ClassName() function call

Tags: java, delphi, c++builder

I am trying to access Java classes dynamically from *.apk file using C++ Builder (Android development). For this purpose I have found complete guide with example in Delphi (here: http://www.pclviewer.com/android/androidJNI.html). Everything works fine in Delphi, but when I tried to rewrite Pascal source code (at the end of guide) into C++ using C++ Builder XE7, I found curious problem. How to cast Delphi interface into TObject* in C++, properly invoke ClassName() function and get JavaObjectID? I spent a lot of time, but still cannot rewrite these 3 lines of code:

```
var
JavaObject:JObject;
oTemp:TObject;
JavaObjectID:JNIObject;
:
oTemp:=JavaObject as TObject;                   //1. ?
JavaObjectID:=tjavaimport(otemp).GetObjectID;   //2. ?
memo1.Lines.Add(oTemp.ClassName);               //3. ? 
:
```

I have tried differenet type casts, also using GetInterface() method of TObject class, but nothing works. As a C++ programmer I don't understand how is it possible directly cast delphi interface into TObject*.

```
Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::_di_JObject JavaObject;
System::TObject* oTemp; 
Androidapi::Jni::_JNIObject *JavaObjectID;  
:
oTemp = (TObject*)(&JavaObject);   //Compiling ok, but segmentation fault 
?
Memo1->Lines->Add(oTemp->ClassName()); // after ClassName() invoke.
```

Does anybody know. how to rewrite these 3 lines of Pascal code into C++ please? Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: My question is why you are casting an interface to `TObject`. Isn't that something that you should not do?

Comment: This way was used in the Delphi example (http://www.pclviewer.com/android/androidJNI.html) and is fully functional. I tried to rewrite code line by line into C++ Builder project, but discovered, that C++ has not interfaces. Delphi interfaces are imitated by abstract classes with pure virtual functions in C++ Builder. Probably it is possible to rewrite mentioned code by the different manner, or use object code generated by Delphi directly in C++ Builder together with generated *.hpp header, but feeling, that I don't understand basics and cannot rewrite 3 lines from Pascal makes me unhappy.

Comment: It would make much more sense to stick to interfaces. Solve the problem entirely with interfaces, and stop trying to cast to the implementing object. Something that goes completely against the spirit of interfaces.

Comment: Probably you are right. I will try different way. Even though still don't understand how it is possible to write "oTemp:=JavaObject as TObject" in Pascal and then properly get ClassName, which return "TJavaImport". These two entities are completely different also in Pascal. Only thing they have common is, they both supports IUnknown interface. Where the common "ClassName" comes from is a puzzle for me.

Comment: `ClassName` is a method of `TObject`. A Delphi interface may be implemented by an instance of a class, and the `as` cast is a way to retrieve that implementing instance. Of course, some interfaces are external and are not implemented by Delphi objects. For them, the `as` cast will fail.

Comment: I assume the closest C++ Builder equivalent to Delphi's `as` operator is `dynamic_cast`. They behave differently on failure, but otherwise should return a pointer or reference to what you ask for. So, `oTemp = dynamic_cast<TObject*>(JavaObject)`.

Comment: That will not work in C++.  You cannot cast an interface to an object that way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious answers and advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting an interface into an object reference is a Delphi-only feature, there is no equivilent in C++ without delving into the vtable directly.  What you can do, however, is write a function in Delphi that takes an interface as input, casts it, and returns the object as output, and then call that function in C++ code. You can add a Delphi `.pas` file to a C++Builder project, it will generate a C++ `.hpp` file when compiled.

```
unit MyJavaHelper;

interface

uses
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

function JObjectToTObject(JavaObject: JObject): TObject;

implementation

function JObjectToTObject(JavaObject: JObject): TObject;
begin
  Result := JavaObject as TObject;
end;

end.
```

```
#include "MyJavaHelper.hpp"

Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::_di_JObject JavaObject;
System::TObject* oTemp; 
Androidapi::Jni::_JNIObject *JavaObjectID;  

JavaObject = ...;
oTemp = JObjectToTObject(JavaObject);
JavaObjectID = static_cast<TJavaImport*>(otemp)->GetObjectID();   
Memo1->Lines->Add(oTemp->ClassName());
```

Comment: Very good answer, thank you very much. It fully clarifies my problem.

Comment: You almost certainly should not do this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: why? Although the `ClassName()` is not particularly useful, it is perfectly valid to use Delphi code in C++ projects in general. When using Embarcadero's Android JNI Bridge framework to access Android APIs, you need access to Java ObjectIDs to access some of JNI's functionality. If you actually look at the example code in question, it is using the ObjectID to call `TJNIResolver.GetJavaMethodID()` to get a reference to a Java `getIntValue()` object method, and then using `JavaEnv^.CallIntMethod()` to call that method using the ObjectID.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: C++Builder does not have the full platform support that Delphi has. C++Builder always lags behind in functionality when it comes to Embarcadero's frameworks. Some things simply cannot be done in C++ code, you have to resort to Delphi code. And this is one of those cases.

Comment: I agree regarding the general point about platform support lagging. On the specifics though, the interface should expose what's needed. An interface should be just that, and not require any knowledge of the implementation

Comment: It depends on the point of view. From software development point of view it is not probably the best practice. Nevertheless my hunger for deeper knowledge about how Delphi and C++ Builder works forced me to find resolution of this problem. It will also help me to avoid mistakes and wasting of the time for searching casting, which actually doesn't exist in C++. I really appreciate Mr. Lebeau advice. It makes me happy again.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: in general, yes.  But this is not a general case. This is a very specific case where an external wrapper API (JNI) is being called directly and it takes IDs as input instead of interface pointers. Not everything in Java is exposed via nice clean interfaces, sometimes you drop down a level deeper. Think of JNI, or more specifically JNI's reflection model (which the example code is using), as being similar to Delphi's RTTI model. It is possible to discover things by name, get an ID for them, and then call them by their ID with associated parameters.

Comment: Well, if the design requires using such a cast, then I don't much care for the design.

Comment: This approach is very useful, if you need to mix Java libraries with existing Pascal, or C++ code. In my case I need to call only several Java functions from *.apk package. It contains 3rd party communication functions. However whole Android application will be created in C++ Builder, which is very comfortable for me. I can call Java functions from *.apk package in the same way like DLL functions in Windows OS.